# sidebarPanel not resizing with plotOutput

Tags: r, shiny

Overall, my goal is to include a set of UI elements inside a grey box. It's purely an aesthetic thing and I've used `sidebarPanel()` to try to accomplish it.

I have run into an issue regarding the layout of my UI in `shiny` when using a `sidebarPanel()` within a `mainPanel`. It looks as if the `sidebarPanel()` changes the spacing between plots and other UI elements on the page. I have included a reproducible example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ###Outputting data exploration graph
  output$graphMain <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(x=hp))
  })
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel = NULL,sidebarPanel = NULL,
  mainPanel = mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      type = "pills",
      tabPanel("My Panel",
               sidebarPanel(width=12 ####Problematic sidebarPanel
                            , checkboxInput(inputId="checkbox1",label="Check box 1")
               ), 
               plotOutput("graphMain", width = "95%") 
               ,checkboxInput(inputId="checkbox2",label="Check Box 2")
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T) )
```

Below shows the issue highlighted with a red circle:
[image]

I dug a little further into this and noticed that the issue appears to be restricted to overlaps with `plotOutput()`'s only. For example, I tried replacing my `plotOutput("graphMain"...)` with a `dataTableOutput()` and the issue went away.

*My question is:* Is there a quick fix to this? I know I can fix it by adding in a bunch of `br()`s but I want to avoid that. Also, if there is a better way to put a set of inputs in a grey box please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ###Outputting data exploration graph
  output$graphMain <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(x=hp))
  })
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel = NULL,sidebarPanel = NULL,
  mainPanel = mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      type = "pills",
      tabPanel("My Panel",
               sidebarPanel(width=12 ####Problematic sidebarPanel
                            , checkboxInput(inputId="checkbox1",label="Check box 1")
               ), 
               fluidRow(verticalLayout(plotOutput("graphMain", width = "95%") 
               ,checkboxInput(inputId="checkbox2",label="Check Box 2"))))
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T))
```